# Project Management software or hosted solution for teams

Tags: web-development, project-management, time-management, cloud-service, self-hosted

I am looking for a Project Management solution for a web development team with the following details:

- Add clients, keep contact informations and upload related files.
- Create different accounts for each member of the team.
- Assign tasks to each client.
- Assign tasks to each member of the team.
- Live time tracking (not manual input) per tasks and per developer.
- Option to time track two different members on the same task.
- Show stats and/or graphs for tasks and time tracking per client, per project, per team member in selected period of time.
- Set monthly available hours for time tracking per client.
- Notifications to team members when a new task is created and assigned to them.
- It can be either self hosted or cloud service.
- It can be free or paid.
- Available for up to 10 team members.

Comment: Have you already checked some of the existing [questions tagged project-management](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management?sort=frequent)? Several of them seem to fit your requirements (at least at a brief glance).

Comment: @Izzy I did for the most voted and couldn't find something that cover all of the above. If I missed something, can you please clarify which one so we can mark this as duplicate? If there isn't one already that cover them, then I would be thankful if we leave it open

Comment: I'm not 100% sure for all your requirements, but most of them are satisfied by Edgewall's *Trac* (recommended a couple of times here) via plugins/addons. There are hundreds of those things you can plug in, like Gantt graphs, tracking time-spent-on-a-task, etc. It's free, and you can self-host it.

Answer (score 1):

We have used [Trello.com](https://trello.com/) combined with the [Plus for Trello Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/plus-for-trello-time-trac/gjjpophepkbhejnglcmkdnncmaanojkf?hl=en) to do all of the things you list here except "time tracking per client" and "Set monthly available hours for time tracking per client.".

I know you can track time by client, we just didn't.
We had twenty people in our organization on our boards.
Sometimes five or more people attached to a card (task)
Time tracking with the Plus extension works by Clicking on "Start" in a task and again to end the timer. (Then enter a description of work performed and a notice to the next person assigned to the task)

Trello is free but they have a gold version which adds some nicer features.
Plus for Trello is also free but the pro version adds some of the features you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since the question was posted, but if anyone is still looking for a similar solution, check out [Teamhood](https://teamhood.com/use-cases/project-management/).

It has most of the above-mentioned features with the exception of 'Set monthly available hours for time tracking per client'. There is no specific feature for that, but the status could be tracked with custom Dashboards.

Teamhood is free for up to 5 users so you could give it a shot.